# error (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize' in opencv had no problem on Macos but error occur with Windows

Tags: python, opencv

I write the code on the mac and it run correctly but when I put the code to run on Windows it shows an error
error (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty()

```
for img_path in images_path:
    # Loading image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    # Detecting objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
        img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)
```

problem occurs around these line of code
I don't have a Windows laptop with me right now

How can I fix that
it is a company's laptop which had to enter password for any permission.
I cannot upgrade the opencv even  have entered password
Is the version of the opencv matter with this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. For example, how is `images_path` obtained? Maybe, you have some OS specific stuff in the code before, we can't see right now.

Comment: ```images_path = glob.glob(folder_selected+"/*")
```
folder_selected is a variable for receive path that I selected
I try to loop every images in the folders

Answer (score 0):

(-215:Assertion failed) means openCV could not find a media file at that particular location that you specified
OR
for video: (-215:Assertion failed) means your video ran out of frames and raised this error

Comment: why it cannot on windows while on mac perform correctly

Comment: @Khemakorn Check all libraries, compare them with mac

Comment: I think it is about path when I try to print path from the windows it contains double backslash in the image section and when I copied path and pasted on the windows explorer it does not found but if I change the \\ to / as normal it found

for example
```
C:/Users/woradate.pat/Downloads/PPE_Detectio
n/PPE_Detection/Sample_Input/had_no_email_in_folder/pk23_CPFM_‡ø◊ËÕßøÈ.jpg',